# batch create subfolders and copy parent image files to new subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file

i have around 6000 folders with images inside them, each folder has a different number of images, and some of them have 0 images also. 
now i need to create 2 subfolders inside each folder, naming these new subfolders with the names “medium” and “thumbs” and copy inside these subfolders the images that are present in the parent folder. Example: lets say i have a folder named 1000 with 10 images inside it, named 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg etc until 10.jpg. I need to create a folder named “medium” and a folder named “thumbs” inside the folder named 1000, and copy the images that are present in the folder 1000 to both new subfolders “1000/medium” and “1000/thumbs”. And i need to do this with something like 6000 folders. Anyone can help me to create a batch routine to do this?

i am trying to write a code like this:

```
for /r "c:\folders" %%a in (.) do ( pushd %%a -iname '*.jpg' -execdir \ bash -c 'mkdir -p thumbs medium; mv *.jpg medium; cp -t thumbs medium/*' \; ) popd )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... As per one of your [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154916/batch-create-subfolders-and-copy-parent-image-files-to-new-subfolders#comment54122923_33155283), you want to have a Windows batch file. You are mixing it up with bash (Linux).

Anyway, `for` is a good choice. However, you will need its `/D` switch to enumerate *directories*. `/R` just tells `for` to search items also in subdirectories, but in your case this is not necessary, because you have a flat directory structure (all directories of interest are directly located in `C:\folders\`).

The following code should do what you are looking for:

```
for /D %%D in ("C:\folders\*.*") do (
    pushd "%%~D"
    mkdir "medium"
    mkdir "thumbs"
    copy "*.jpg" "medium\"
    copy "*.jpg" "thumbs\"
    popd
)
```

If you want the original files to be removed, replace the second `copy` command by `move`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it with `find -execdir`

```
find path/to/6000/folders -iname '*.jpg' -execdir \
    bash -c 'mkdir -p thumbs medium; mv *.jpg medium; cp -t thumbs medium/*' \;
```

Comment: hello, thank you so much. I would like to ask the following, i have around 6000 folders, will the code you wrote work by opening each one of the 6000 folders that are located inside a specific folder and create the "medium" and "thumbs" under each folder? or should i run this folder by folder? thanks really SO much. lets say I have the 6000 folders under the path c:/folders, should I use the script in the following way?

Comment: `find c:/folders -iname '*.jpg' -execdir \
    bash -c 'mkdir -p thumbs medium; mv *.jpg medium; cp -t thumbs medium/*' \; `

Comment: also, I was trying to understand the `FOR` command, maybe I should add something like this to the script in order to run the command in every subfolder? what do you think? `FOR /D %d IN (*.*) DO @ECHO %d`

Comment: This is not a [tag:batch-file] code; note that [tag:bash] is something completely different...

Comment: well, I need a batch-file code, DOS code.. not a linux code.